# Problem with viewing bam file downloaded from geo

Tags: samtools, bam

I downloaded a dataset in the BAM Format from GEO using  the command:
`prefetch SRR13558458`
It generates a file names "SRR13558458.sra".

I would like to view this file using samtools. But it seems this sra file which is a bam file is not readable using samtools view command!

First I tried to chage the sra file to bam using the following command:
`sam-dump --output-file SRR13558458.bam SRR13558458`
sam-dump generates an empty file!

Besides, when I change the file extension:
 `mv SRR13558458.sra SRR13558458.bam`
`samtools view SRR13558458.bam | less`

I got this error:

> [E::hts_hopen] Failed to open file SRR13558458.bam
> [E::hts_open_format] Failed to open file "SRR13558458.bam" : Exec format error
> samtools view: failed to open "SRR13558458.bam" for reading: Exec format error

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks!